# Rails 5.0.2 - ID in relation belongs_to/has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new on RAILS, so don't hit me.
I consider such problem:

```
- author
    has_many :books
- book
    belongs_to :author
```

In console I create a new author, per example:

```
ar = Author.new(fname: "Frank", lname: "Herbert")
```

ID of this record is not set before save.

Then I create some books from object ar:

```
ar.books.new(title: "Dune"), ar.books.new(title: "The Green Brain")
```

No errors. But when I list books:

```
ar.books.all
```

got an empty list.
I figured out that first I have to save `ar`, and then I can add books.

Is there a way to save `ar` with books, no need saving `ar` without books before?

Comment: as  i know, answer is no. first, you have to create an author record with id, which will be used in books as a foreign key.

Comment: So, it complicates nested forms, when I create a **new** author and I try to add some books

Comment: @KilgoreTrout its complex to create Author first and then create books, try to create both at one time. You can check my posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below code:
First create Author and then create books with author as foreign key.

```
ar = Author.new(fname: "Frank", lname: "Herbert")
ar.save

ar.books.create(title: "Dune")
ar.books.create(title: "The Green Brain")
```

OR

```
ar = Author.new(fname: "Frank", lname: "Herbert")
ar.books.build(title: "Dune")
ar.books.build(title: "The Green Brain")
ar.save
```

Comment: You can use create for Author instead of new+save.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can!

You need to call `ar.books` to look up for books that you have added. When you call `ar.books.all` ActiveRecord tries to find something in database (obviously it returns empty array). So just:

```
author = Author.new(fname: "Frank", lname: "Herbert")
author.books.build(title: "Dune")
author.save
```

It will save author & books as you expect. By the way use `build` method instead of `new`. In this way you show that you are going to create record soon.

Comment: Use build or new, it doesn't matter since `build` is just an alias of `new` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L124

Comment: Exactly, you are right, this is the same method! I wrote it because `build` method is showing your intentions. Generally `new` method is using in commands to initialize object and then pass it somewhere.